# How I can get value of formula without changing actual reference's value

Tags: excel

I have an excel table that calculates a lot of things according to input cells value. But if I want to get value of formula output, I have to change all related cell value.

For example

```
A1: 2 | B1: 5 | C1: =A1+B1
```

I want to get value of C1 without changing A1 like

```
(assume A1=5;C1)
```

And output that What I expected is that:

```
A1: 2 | B1: 5 |C1: =A1+B1 |D1 =Assume(A1=5,C1)
```

`D1` value expected as `5+5=10` without changing A1 to "5". But I couldn't figure out which function does this work.

How can I do this if 20+ cell output value combined each other? For example A1 and B1 are input, C1 to AC1 are output (calculates formula).

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Just a guess, but I feel you want to put a lambda formula in the name manager: `=LAMBDA(z,z+B1)`  Then you would call that named function.  So if I saved it as `myFormula` it would be `=myFormula(5)`

Comment: Otherwise I doubt formula will do what you want.

Comment: it seems to me that you want to have smth like `=IF(some condition,A1,5)`. Now what is the condition, I cannot quite figure out.

Comment: @DataBunny Sorry for bad explaination. But I want give specific value to specific cell without changing the real value. And there are a lot of cell effected this number and output change. And the formula is complex not just adding value. Some of them like İf(cond;true;false) and the cond checks effected number from input cells. And the calculation is complex math algorithm. Actually what I want is that "If I put a value to A1, table that calculates about 20+ cells and all value changing. I want just specific cell value like C1 if I put A1 as 5". I hope you understand what I asked.

Comment: @ScottCraner this cell is just example but my math is combined also different calculation like multiples, if condition etc. But this just add value to C1. Not what I asked for.

Comment: A formula will not be able to do this.

Comment: @makgun you say " I want is that "If I put a value to A1, table that calculates about 20+ cells and all value changing." So basically, you say that want a switch that on activation will update values from some other, possibly external source. What is this [external] source?